# Can we use SPSiteDataQuery in JSOM OUT OF BOX?

Tags: jsom

I would like to know weather we can use SPSiteDataQuery in JSOM or not.
If yes request anyone to please guide me .

we all knew that SpSiteDataQuery is Much faster when compared to SPQuery, And I am retrieving some large amount of list items

Answer (score 1):

JSOM does not provide a mechanism for querying data across multiple lists that are not associated by a lookup field. In other words, there is no client-side functional equivalent of the SPSiteDataQuery class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx

You can leverage Search APIs to get results from multiple sub sites.
See this article about SharePoint 2013 search Query APIs:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/using-the-sharepoint-search-query-apis